# pseudo-dimension for knapsack problem

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, learning-theory

Let $v_i, s_i$ be the value and size of item $i$, let $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$, n be the maximum number of items. Then we add items based on $\frac{v_i}{s_i^{\rho}}$ in decreasing order. I was trying to understand a proof in a paper, but I get stuck at some points. The utility function $u_{\rho}$ is the value of items selected by the greedy algorithm for an given input x under a parameter setting $\rho$.
*Fix some instance x. Suppose Algorithm $A_{\rho_1}$ produces a different solution on x than $A_{\rho_2}$ for $\rho_1 < \rho_2$. Consider the first point they differ, $A_{\rho_1}$ adds item i while $A_{\rho_2}$ adds item j. Then it must be he case that $\frac{v_i}{s_i^{\rho_1}} - \frac{v_j}{s_j^{\rho_1}} \geq 0, \frac{v_i}{s_i^{\rho_2}} - \frac{v_j}{s_j^{\rho_2}} \leq 0$. Consider the function $f(\rho) = \frac{v_i}{s_i^{\rho}} - \frac{v_j}{s_j^{\rho}}$. This is a continuous function and there must exist some value $c \in [\rho_1, \rho_2]$ such that $f(\rho) = 0$.
For any given pair of items $i, j$, there is ***at most one value*** of $\rho > 0$ such that $f(\rho) = 0$ and there are at most $\binom{n}{2}$ critical values c. ***By the argument above, the algorithm will produce the same solution for all $\rho$ within the interval between any two consecutive critical values.***
My main confusion comes from the bolded lines. How do the proof conclued there is at most one value $\rho > 0$ such that $f(\rho) = 0$ and how to conclude the algorithm is invariant between two consecutive critical point values?
Here is the link for the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2011.07177.pdf. It was written by Maria-Florina Balcan. I was trying to understand Theorem 2.4 in this paper. I believe this paper is open-sourced, so it contains more details for the proof.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Can you [edit] your post to give a citation to the paper (title, authors, where published, and a link to a freely available copy if possible), and clearly indicate which parts of your question are copied or quotations from the paper?

Comment: I think the paper says "there must exist some value", it does not say at most one.  For any value $\rho$ in that interval, the knapsack items are sorted the same way so the algorithm (described in the paper) will produce the same solution.

Comment: Yes, the paper prove there must exist some value, and then in the third paragraph, it mentions there is at most one parameter setting such that the function achieves 0.

Comment: I think the function $f(\rho)$ is monotone, which would imply it crosses 0 just once in the interval.

Comment: I agree with this idea, but how does this implies the function still produces the same solutions for the next iterations? We are only analyzing the case where the two algorithms produce different solutions for the first time, how about the proceeding solutions?

Comment: Since the algorithm only depends on the order of the items, if two values of $\rho$ produce the same order they will produce the same algorithmic result.   So if $\rho=\rho_1$ you get one algorithmic solution $S$.  If you move $\rho$ up a small amount (not quite up to $c$, and assuming there are no other critical values along the way corresponding to other pairs), you haven't changed the order in any way, so you get $S$ again.  Moving $\rho$ up more (say until $c$) then you get a tie, once you are past $c$ the two items $i$ and $j$ will swap therefore producing a new order and solution $S'$.

Comment: This shows there are at most $n^2$ possible solutions coming from this algorithm, which is all the authors are looking to prove.

Comment: I think your analysis is correct, but I don't agree with your idea that $f(\rho)$ is monotone since the function also depends on the score for item i and item j. Otherwise, the author cannot say that between two consecutive critical values, the solution is the same.

Comment: Say there are two values of $\rho$ where $f(\rho)=0$, say $a$ and $b$.  Then $v_i/s_i^a-v_j/s_j^a=0$ and $v_i/s_i^b-v_j/s_j^b=0$.  Then you see that $a=b$ must be true.